# showing activity indicator within UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to add an activity indicator into an imageView as follows when I am  downloading the contents from url but the problem is that the  activity indicator is not visible.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = nil;

    if ([imageArray count] >0){
        if(cachedImage[[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] != nil){
            recipeImageView.image = cachedImage[[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
        else{
            UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
            activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(140, 236, 37, 37);
            [activityIndicator startAnimating];
            [recipeImageView addSubview:activityIndicator];
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
                NSData *data0 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data0];

                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                    recipeImageView.image = image;
                    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                    cachedImage[[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] = image;
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

How can i be able to show the activity indicator within imageview with progress percent if possible?

Comment: `activityIndicator.center = recipeImageView.center;` Try this.

Comment: @EktaMakadiya That won't work because the centers are not in the same coordinate systems.

Comment: @Learner Check my answer.

Comment: hi, use a library on github called AsyncImageView, it does exactly what you are tying to achieve. you give it url, it shows indicator, download and display image, have a placeholder image, and is customizable. It even cahces the images if you want it to!

Comment: is `CGRectMake(140, 236, 37, 37)` the location even within the `UIImageView`'s bounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update your code and try this

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = nil;

    if ([imageArray count] >0){
        if(cachedImage[[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] != nil){
            recipeImageView.image = cachedImage[[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
        else{
            UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
            [activityIndicator setCenter: recipeImageView.center];
            [activityIndicator startAnimating];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:activityIndicator];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
                NSData *data0 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data0];

                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                    recipeImageView.image = image;
                    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                    cachedImage[[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] = image;
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Man Don't copy and post the answer.Please try to give the sample or tried code solution.

Comment: I saw your posted answer in other stackoverflow related question.

Comment: I just confirmed with one answer. But not copied from there as I did same thing in my application. And look his code is working as he up voted my answer. :)

Comment: When we see answer at least it should be unique.That's why we say.

Comment: Yes I agree, but sometimes we have to copy question and update it. But from next time I will take care of it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        activityIndicator.center = recipeImageView.center; 
        [activityIndicator startAnimating];
        [recipeImageView addSubview:activityIndicator];
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
            NSData *data0 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data0];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                recipeImageView.image = image;
                [activityIndicator stopAnimating]; 
                [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                cachedImage[[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] = image;
            });
        });
```

Comment: @Learner Please Give response. And if this works then please accept it.

Answer (score -1):

```
 UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

[indicator startAnimating];
[indicator setCenter:self.recipeImageView.center];
[self.contentView addSubview:indicator];
```

Comment: it works but it adds six spinners when there are only three images that are getting loaded